# Can't start Jupyter via Docker Entrypoint - `root_dir` and `file_to_run` are incompatible

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm having some weird behaviour w/ my docker/jupyter setup.

My entrypoint looks like this:

```
entrypoint: ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "jupyter", "jupyter","notebook" ]
```

But that fails with:

```
jupyter_dev  | [C 2023-08-29 18:59:51.327 ServerApp] `root_dir` and `file_to_run` are incompatible. They don't share the same subtrees. Make sure `file_to_run` is on the same path as `root_dir`.
```

But, if I comment out the `entrypoint` and then enter container CLI I can run that same command and everything works as expected...